# VirtualBox XPCOM for different users

Tags: c++, virtualbox, xpcom

I'm using VirtualBox's XPCOM to interact with the VirtualBox information.  So far everything works well.  Now I'd like to interact with VirtualBox for different users.  Is there any way to do this?  It seems that the XPCOM only starts the VBoxSVC process for the current user.  Is there any way to have it start it as a different user?  I've looked into using vboxwebsrv as well, but the sdk says that it will only get the VirtualBox information as the user it is started as.

Also, assume I can run the XPCOM client program as root, so it has access to everything.  Is there anything I can do to make this work?